# Schema-validation: missing table [SEQUENCE_NAME] when using Hibernate Sequence Generator Strategy

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, spring-boot, id-generation, sequence-generators

I have some problems with the hibernate id generation and a ms sql server.

I am using the `GenerationType.SEQUENCE` in my application to generate Ids with hibernate.

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "SequenceGenerator", sequenceName = "SEQUENCE_NAME")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SequenceGenerator")
private Long id;
```

As DB I use a microsoft sql server 2017.

I create the sequence via Liquibase:

```
<createSequence incrementBy="50" sequenceName="SEQUENCE_NAME" startValue="100000"/>
```

While starting the Spring Boot Application I get the error:

```
Schema-validation: missing table [SEQUENCE_NAME]
```

When I manually query for the sequence it can be found:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.objects
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[SEQUENCE_NAME]') AND type = 'SO'
```

I am a little bit confused that it says "missing **table**". With oracle it works fine. Does mssql not support id generation via sequences.

My Configuration:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433"
    username: sa
    password: ABc12345!
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
```

I use this docker image: `mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-CU12-ubuntu`

Comment: Yes, it's not supported for SQL Server. Refer to Database Support table at https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/create_sequence.html

Comment: Yes, but the sequence was created. I could query it afterwards. And also 
`Select NEXT VALUE FOR SEQUENCE_NAME` returned a new id.

Comment: Hmm, maybe you've misconfigured hibernate... show your config file (application.properties/.yml by default)

Comment: i mean not whole file, but those parts where JPA/Hibernate properties are placed

Comment: I added the configuration to the question above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used the wrong dialect in the configuration.
The correct one is:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
```

The other one is for older servers which doesn't support sequences.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `default_schema` to application.yml:

```
spring:
   jpa:
      properties:
         hibernate:
            default_schema: "dbo"
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Problem is still the same. I now realized that the error also appears for the `hibernate_sequence`